# Error using innerSize in highcharts when build android - ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I'm using highcharts with ionic 3.
established the property:
  innerSize: '40% ',
In the emulator it works correctly, but with cordova build android I get the following error.

I want to use a chart like this example:
https://www.highcharts.com/samples/codepen/highcharts/demo/pie-donut

**Any ideas?
How can I skip errors in ionic 3?
how to disable tslint?**

```
Argument of type '{ colors: string[]; chart: { plotBackgroundColor: null; plotBorderWidth                               : null; plotShadow:
        false;...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'. Types of property 'series' a                               re incompatible.
        Type '{ name: string; data: any[]; innerSize: string; }[]' is not assignable to type
        'IndividualSeriesOptions[]'. Type '{ name: string; data: any[]; innerSize: string; }' is                                not assignable to
        type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'in                               nerSize' does not
        exist in type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'.

 L340:      innerSize: '40%',
 L341:  }]
```

Comment: You aren't showing us any code, which makes it hard to help. But the error message is quite explicit in what seems to be wrong. You are passing some object that is expected to be of a certain type, but the objects you are sending does not match those signatures

Comment: I want to use a chart like this example.
All work fine but the only error is in the attribute innerSize when run 
ionic cordova build android
https://www.highcharts.com/samples/codepen/highcharts/demo/pie-donut